# Why does constraining auto with an integral type render it uninvocable for views::filter?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have written a simple predicate which I want to pass to `std::ranges::views::filter`:

```
struct even_fn {
    constexpr
    bool operator()(std::integral auto&& e) const noexcept {
        return e % 2 == 0;
    }
};

inline constexpr even_fn even;
```

Sample usage:

```
using namespace std::ranges;
views::iota(1, 10) | views::filter(even);
```

This fails with a wall of errors with, I presume, the most meaningful one being:

> ```
> note: the expression 'is_invocable_v<_Fn, _Args ...> [with _Fn = even_fn&; _Args = {std::__detail::__cond_value_type<int>::value_type&}]' evaluated to 'false'
> ```

However, if I remove the `std::integral` part from my operator (leaving just `auto&&`), the code compiles successfully. Why is that? What's so special about this `__cond_value_type` that breaks when we have constrained functors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `std::integral` won't allow reference types to be deduce.

In effect, the filter view will filter with something kind of like this:

```
filter_function(*it);
```

This, with most range type will return a lvalue reference to the element.

Since it send a lvalue reference, the only way to make the call to your function is to deduce `int&`, so the reference collapsing work that way: `int& && --> int&`. Without that calling your function with lvalue is impossible.

But `int&` is not an integral type, hence your error!

How can you make your filter work then?

Simply drop the forwaring reference and use a const lvalue reference:

```
struct even_fn {
    constexpr
    bool operator()(std::integral auto const& e) const noexcept {
        return e % 2 == 0;
    }
};
```

That way, when deducing from a int lvalue, simply `int` will be deduced to make the call work.

---

With concept template parameter, it would be possible to with a higher order concept to make this case work:

```
template<typename T, concept C>
concept forwarded = C<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;
```

And use it like this:

```
struct even_fn {
    constexpr
    bool operator()(forwarded<std::integral> auto&& e) const noexcept {
        return e % 2 == 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: so basically a `T&&` with `<std::integral T>` behaves differently than a `T&&` with `<typename T>`? More precisely, the former is not a universal reference?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. It's still a universal reference but the concept applies not to `auto` but to `auto&&`. IMO that's very unintuitive, but I guess it has to be like that.

Comment: @Sopel No, `auto` is deduced as `int&`.

Comment: Why not `bool operator()(auto&& e) requires std::integral<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(e)>>`?

Comment: @PasserBy because in this case, forwarding in not needed at all. The correct solution is to take a `const&`. In other cases yes, this would be a solution.